# Merge values with same key in object Javascript

Tags: javascript

What is the best way to merge array contents from JavaScript objects sharing a key in common?

How can array in the example below be reorganized into output? Here, all value keys (whether an array or not) are merged into all objects sharing the same name key.

```js
const array = 
[
  {
    brand: ['Adidas', 'Nike']
    color: ['red']
  },
  {
    brand: ['Puma', 'Nike'],
    size: ['31', '32']
  }
]

/* Expect output
[{
  brand: ['Adidas', 'Puma', 'Nike'],
  size: ['31', '32']
  color: ['red']
}] 
*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```js
const array = 
[
  {
    brand: ['Adidas', 'Nike'],
    color: ['red']
  },
  {
    brand: ['Puma', 'Nike'],
    size: ['31', '32']
  }
]

const res = array.reduce((prev, curr) => {
   for(let key in curr) {
      if(!prev[key]) {
          prev[key] = curr[key]
      } else {
          prev[key].push(...curr[key])
      }
   }
   return prev
}, {})

console.log(res)
```

Comment: This gives a wrong answer: `res.brand` will be `["Adidas", "Nike", "Puma", "Nike"]`, with `"Nike"` duplicated (as opposed to the desired `["Adidas", "Puma", "Nike"]`). Also, note that this solution is destructive: if you change input, the result also changes. E.g. if you execute the above, then execute `array[0].color.push('blue')`, suddenly `res.color` is `["red", "blue"]`. This may or may not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution which @norbekoff has given will reduce all elements of array into one element. It is suitable if the objects in the array has only one common key.

But what if array is like

```js
const array = [
    {
      brand: ['Adidas', 'Nike'],
      color: ['red']
    },
    {
      brand: ['abcd'],
    },
    {
      brand: ['Puma', 'Nike'],
      size: ['31', '32']
    },
    {
      brand1: ['Bata'],
      size: ['31', '32']
    },
    {
      brand1: ['Woodland']
    }
  ]
```

I tried with the below code and it worked:

```js
const array = [
    {
      brand: ['Adidas', 'Nike'],
      color: ['red']
    },
    {
      brand: ['abcd'],
    },
    {
      brand: ['Puma', 'Nike'],
      size: ['31', '32']
    },
    {
      brand1: ['Bata'],
      size: ['31', '32']
    },
    {
      brand1: ['Woodland']
    }
  ]

var keys = array.flatMap(a => Object.keys(a))
var duplicateKeys = keys.filter(key => keys.indexOf(key) != keys.lastIndexOf(key))
duplicateKeys = [... new Set(duplicateKeys)]
var newArr = []

duplicateKeys.forEach(key => {
    let common = array.filter(a => a.hasOwnProperty(key))
    let temp = {};
    temp[key] = []
    common.forEach(c => {
        temp[key].push(...c[key])
        let cKeys = Object.keys(c);
        cKeys.map(k => k != key ? temp[k] = c[k] : null)
    })
    newArr.push(temp)
});

console.log(newArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

To start with, an easy way to remove duplicates is to create a `Set`. `new Set(["brand", "color", "brand", "size"])` will create a three-element set; if we then convert it back into an array (Using `Array.from`, or deconstructing it with `[...set]`), we will get something like `["brand", "color", "size"]`. Using this pattern, we can take the union of keys, then calculate the union of values for each key:

```js
const array = 
[
  {
    brand: ['Adidas', 'Nike'],
    color: ['red'],
  },
  {
    brand: ['Puma', 'Nike'],
    size: ['31', '32']
  },
]

const result =
  // find all the keys as the union of the keys of each item
  [...new Set(array.flatMap(Object.keys))]
  .reduce(
    // for each key, find the values
    (result, key) => {
      // the values are the union of all the values under the same key
      result[key] = [...new Set(array.flatMap(item => item[key] ?? []))];
      return result;
    }, {}
  );
  
console.log(result);
```